# How to create a NumberFormat in Java that supports both an upper-case and a lower-case E as an Exponent Separator?

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have the following code:

```
NumberFormat numberInstance = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
System.out.println(numberInstance.parse("6.543E-4"));
System.out.println(numberInstance.parse("6.543e-4"));
```

which produces the following output:

```
6.543E-4
6.543
```

Is there a way to tweak a NumberFormat to recognize both an upper- and lower-case E as the exponent separator? Is there a best work-around? Anything better than running toUpper() on the input first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is "no", not directly.

Although using `toUpperCase()` directly on the input is a small coding overhead to pay for consistency, there is this workaround:

```
NumberFormat numberInstance = new NumberFormat() {
    @Override
    public Number parse(String str) {
        return super.parse(str.toUpperCase());
    }
};
```

This is an anonymous class that overrides the `parse()` method to imbue case insensitivity to its implementation.

Comment: Agreed, its capital E as per implementation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: It occurs that we could also use `str.replace('e', 'E')`

Answer (score 1):

At least Double.parseDouble accepts both

```
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("6.543e-4"));
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("6.543E-4"));
```

output

```
6.543E-4
6.543E-4
```

as for NumberFormat we can change E to e as

```
    DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    DecimalFormatSymbols s = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    s.setExponentSeparator("e");
    nf.setDecimalFormatSymbols(s);
    System.out.println(nf.parse("6,543e-4"));
```

output

```
6.543E-4
```

but now it does not accept E :(