# DecimalFormat.parse() ignoring exponents

Tags: java, parsing, bigdecimal

I am trying to parse Strings containing decimals (that may or may not use scientific notation) into `BigDecimal`.

`DecimalFormat.parse()` seems to work fine for numbers that do not use scientific notation, but `3.95e-06` is getting parsed as the double `3.95` (the exponent is being ignored).

I am familiar with the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor but `DecimalFormat` affords me a more flexible parsing format (e.g. for currencies).

What is the appropriate way to parse decimals, with or without exponential notation, into `BigDecimal`?

Comment: *the BigDecimal(String) constructor* is the correct way. `DecimalFormat` doesn't support `BigDecimal`. Good luck!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Given that `DecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal()` exists, I don't think you can say that it does not support `BigDecimal`. Clearly someone thought to add support.

Comment: And how's that working for 'ya?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch: OP is right. DecimalFormat **does** support BigDecimal, it is just a bit finicky WRT upper case/lower case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `DecimalFormat` expects a capital `E` and *not* a lowercase `e`, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925393/1707091).

But you can always uppercase the string.  Then you can call [`setParseBigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setParseBigDecimal-boolean-) and set it to `true` so that `parse` returns a `BigDecimal`.

Testing scientific and normal notation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    test("3.95e-06");
    test("12345");
}

private static void test(String line) throws Exception {
    DecimalFormat bdf = new DecimalFormat();
    double d = bdf.parse(line.toUpperCase()).doubleValue();
    System.out.println(d);
    bdf.setParseBigDecimal(true);
    BigDecimal test = (BigDecimal) bdf.parse(line.toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Output:  The `double` then the `BigDecimal` output for each string:

```
3.95E-6
0.00000395
12345.0
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

`DecimalFormat` seems to be thrown off by the lowercase `e`. Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925393/14731 this doesn't seem to be fixable.